# How to cancel context in a goroutine by passing the context but without passing the cancel function

Tags: go

I am learning the Go language...

I understand how a context can be cancelled using the cancel() function. But consider the following scenario:

```
 package main
 
 import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
 )
 
 func task1(ctx context.Context, cancel func()) {
 
    go func() { //Cancel after 3 seconds of work
        //If I derive a new context here and use its cancel function
        //then that cancel function does not cancel the parent context.
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        cancel()
    }()
 
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("ctx Cancelled in task1")
    }
 
 }
 
 func main() {
 
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
 
    go task1(ctx, cancel)
 
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("ctx Cancelled in main")
    }
    
    //Wait for task1 to print its message
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
 
 }
```

Here the cancel function is passed to the task1 Goroutine. If I derive another context from the parent in task1 function() and use that cancel function, I noticed that it cancels the derived context and its children and not the parent context. If task1 is defined within main, then cancel function of the parent context will be in the task1 goroutine's scope and there is no need to pass it as an argument.  But I want to cancel the context in the task1 function in the scenario given above.  Is there any way to get the cancel function of a given context? The Context interface itself does not seem to give any method to do so.

Comment: In addition to the answer linked above you might find [this blog entry](https://go.dev/blog/context) useful; particularly the bit around "when a parent operation starts goroutines for sub-operations, those sub-operations should not be able to cancel the parent"

Comment: @Brits Yes, the question "Cancel context from Child" answers my question. Answers the very doubts that I had. However, IMHO  it would be incorrect to generalize that "when a parent operation... ...should not be able to cancel the parent." It will be application specific and some applications may need to cancel the parent if an error occurs in the child.

Comment: If you need the ability to cancel a parent context then there are options for that (e.g. pass in the `CancelFunc`). Doing it this way makes things explicit. The interaction between go routines can become very complex and its easy to introduce bugs; keeping things as explicit as possible makes this easier (see @icza answer in the linked question for more)..

Comment: @Brits Indeed all the answers in the linked question are informative. I should have read all of them earlier. Thanks.

Comment: You may find [the errgroup package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) useful.

Comment: @Peter  Yes I have looked at the errgroup package too.  The context returned by it does not have a cancel function and deriving a context with cancel will not work for the group's Go method. Anyhow, that is just my recollection. I will take another look at it.

Comment: The context returned by errgroup is cancelled automatically as soon as one of the functions returns an error. It seemed to me that's what you wanted, but perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @Peter  errgroup has its own use, no doubt. But it also has limitations. Applications may like to wait for all functions to return and report all errors from all functions and then cancel the context based upon application logic. errgroup does not allow this. But, as I said, for certain applications errgroup is perfect. For more complex applications, customization can be done using the basic context package itself with channels and other support from golang.